# Using JSON-Object in jqueryUI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I'm loading a JSON array from an external Domain. I have gotten this to work correctly yet I am still having problems actually showing any of the results.
Using examples and other question/answers I have gotten as far as an attempt of displaying the results apparently being made, but ending in an uncaught error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined

Code snippet:

```
$('#citySearchBox').autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response){
          $.ajax({
              url: "/api.php",
              data: {action: "search", input: request.term},
              dataType: "jsonp"
          });
          response(function(data){
              return $.parseJSON(data);
          });
      },
      minLength: 3
  });
```

Server Response as seen in debugger:

> [{"id":"1.3.0.0.0.0","label":"Berlin
>   (10115)","value":"index.php?action=city&city=1.3.0.0.0.0"}, *etc...*]

As you can see I have attempted to parse the string into a JS Object, with shown method and also tried `JSON.parse(data)`.

If I've made a mistake earlier than the "response" part but somehow managed to half-way bodge it please point out my mistakes.

**EDIT:**

I've changed the code after Bradys suggestion, but I seem to be doing something wrong with the syntax, as putting a break-point inside of the response function nothing is stopped.

This is the updated response function:

```
response( function(data){
        var items = data.text().slice(1, -1).split(',');
        for(i=0; i < (items.length - 3); i=i+3)
        {
            items[i] = $.parseJSON(items[i]) + ','
             + $.parseJSON(items[i+1]) + ',' + $.parseJSON(items[i+2]);
        }
        return items;
    });
```

**Case closed, never actually got JSONP to work, but the situation changed and was no longer reliant on cross-domain communication.**

For anybody interested working code is as follows:

```
  $('#searchBox').autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response){
          $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "api.php",
              async: true,
              data: {action: "search", input: request.term},
              success: function(data){
                  var items  = $.parseJSON(data);
                  response(items);
              }
          });
      },
      select: function(event, ui){
          $('#searchBox').val(ui.item.value);
          window.location.href = ui.item.url;
      },
      minLength: 2
  });
```

Comment: I think you need to drop the first line and run your loop on `data`.  Notice that there are no quotes surrounding the server response that you pasted above.  I believe you have a pure array.   

This might be happening because of your use of `jsonp` instead of `json`.  I don't think you need `jsonp` here, it's for making request cross-domain and leaves you with executable JavaScript.  More details of the proper use of `jsonp` can be found on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about

Comment: Thank you for your help. At the time of asking I was working cross-domain, but that has changed so I got rid of the jsonp and now everything works fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're getting from the server is not a JSON string.  It's an array.
You should split up the array and parse each object individually.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've made the changes to the code after your suggestions, but have explained my further problem in the edit.